# How do I join two UV islands into one making it better for unwrapping?

Tags: uv

How do I join two parts into one making it better for unwrapping? One part was mirrored and joined in the middle, doubles removed.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader for images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found out why it did not unwrap into 1 piece.
The ends had ngons so when I joined the 2 pieces in the middle they were still there when I joined the vertices in the centre. Now removed the 2 un-needed faces and unwraps nicely.